# Using log axes scales in ggplot from Rpy2

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, rpy2

I am trying to format my axes on a log scale from Rpy2 using ggplot.  In ordinary R, it's possible to do:

```
qplot(data=data, x=x, y=y) + geom_point() + scale_y_log2()
```

To get a log2 axis. When I try to use `ggplot2.scale_y_log2` in Rpy2, it complains that it's not found, although `ggplot2.scale_x_log10` (log**10**) works fine. How can I get log2 axes in Rpy2?

Related question: if my data is already logged (e.g. it's in a Pandas dataframe where I applied log2 to the rows), how can I get ggplot in Rpy2 to just format the axis as a log axis (i.e. ticks like 2^1, 2^2, 2^4, ...) without taking the log again of the data? Just a reformatting of the labels, since the data is already in log values.  thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a Python / rpy2 question, the code in Python:

```
from rpy2.robjects.lib import ggplot2
from rpy2.robjects import r
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

scales = importr('scales')

iris = r('iris')

p = ggplot2.ggplot(iris) + \
    ggplot2.geom_point(ggplot2.aes_string(x="Sepal.Length", y="Sepal.Width")) + \
    ggplot2.scale_x_continuous(trans = scales.log2_trans())

p.plot()
```

Comment: The wrapping of `ggplot2` in `rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2` is taking a very small number of liberties. One of them is that to make a plot for a ggplot construct the method is called `plot()`, not `print()` (it felt less confusing).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! good stuff for rpy2! I have juste a question ( sorry for asking here) , does rpy2 is used in a real business application?

Comment: I'll keep away from giving examples for fear to start against my will a debate about what is a "real business" ;-), but from what I am gathering it is. In a rather wide range of fields.

Comment: @lgautier: but doesn't `ggplot2.scale_x_continuous(trans = scales.log2_trans())` actually apply log to the data?  My data is already logged. So imagine that `iris` is already in log values, and I just want the axis to follow.  I don't want plotting to transform my data; the data is already transformed and kept in log form in a dataframe.

Comment: @user248237 : If your data are already logged, then do not apply the transformation and you are set. If you want the tick marks and labels to follow a log transform, you'll have to 1) start from non-log-transformed data 2) use `coord_trans(x="log2")` instead of `scale_x_continuous(trans = scales.log2_trans())`

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first part of the question , you can't do this in R:

```
qplot(data=data, x=x, y=y) + geom_point() + scale_y_log2()
```

you get this error :

```
   Error: could not find function "scale_y_log2"
```

So, you have to define it before:

```
library(scales)
scale_y_log2 <- function (...) 
{
  scale_y_continuous(..., trans = log2_trans())
}
dat <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10)
qplot(data=dat, x=x, y=y) + geom_point() + scale_y_log2()
```

Comment: +1 for showing how to add scales with a one-line-body function.